# How is the window scale set/calculated in the TCP/IP implementation of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

Can someone point out the exact location in the kernel source tree and the exact algorithm of how the window scale of a TCP packet is calculated/set in the linux kernel?

Most other TCP options like the ttl and window buffer size seem to be directly hardcoded in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The window scale of a TCP packet isn't calculated at all. TCP packets don't have window scales. Connections have window scales, and it is fixed when the connection is completed, based on the size of the socket receive buffer and possibly any system defaults, in such a way that any 16 bit value shifted by the scale can encompass the entire socket receive buffer.

Comment: I see. I am interested in the initial window scale option offered on the first SYN packet. 
I think this is a good place to start to understand how it's calculated and what factors influence it: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L581

Comment: And I guess here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L208

Answer (score -1):

The best place to check out the congestion avoidance modules is in the Linux source for the Linux Reno implementation. You can find this in the net/ipv4/tcp_cong.c file:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp_cong.c

The net/ipv4/tcp_input.c file invokes the modules and is generally a good area to understand how the overall logic works:

git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c

Also, RFC 5681 specifies the Reno congestion control actions in detail, and may be helpful in understanding the kernel code. If you find the above article too coarse, give the below link a look. It contains excerpts from the above article, however it removes some of the redundant information:

github.com/romain-jacotin/quic/blob/master/doc/TCPCongestionControl.md

Comment: Congestion avoidance != window scale.